# Can i compute the "Look up names" property in Names-Field

Tags: lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula, lotus-notes

I have a Lotus Notes form with a field type "Names". 
On the control-tab of the field you can mark the "Look up names as each character is entered".

[image: Names-Field, second tab]

Is there a way to compute this option based on a flag in the document?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way that I know, is to use a computed subform.
if the doc has the flag, show subform with field that have the property "Look up names as each character is entered".
if the doc has not the flag, show subform with field that not have the property "Look up names as each character is entered".

Comment: Yeah, i think that is an acceptable way. I've totally forgotten the little "Insert Subform based on formula" checkbox ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Using a subform as stated by adminfd is one possibility. But it has some disadvantages:

1. you don't see the content of a computed subform in designer and cannot double click (inconvenient for developers).
2. using a lot of subforms can make loading the form very slow

I usually do things like that with additional fields. I make the field itself hidden and computed with the formula:

```
@If( YourCondition; FieldNameWithLookup; FieldNameWithoutLookup );
```

Then I create two fields above the hidden field, name them `FieldNameWithLookup` and `FieldNameWithoutLookup` and hide them using the same condition as in the Value- Formula of the field.

Yes, it produces some overhead as there are two additional fields, that are not necessary, but I simply like this approach more.

If you have existing documents, then you need the formula `FieldName` in the two new fields as default values and probably some code, if the Condition value for displaying one or the other field changes during different states of the document...

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! You're right with your points and we could add to the list, that you will recieve "double field"-warnings only at runtime. Therefore, your suggested solution is a nice alternative.

Comment: @Richard: Why did you take out runfaster? Did you try? This is NOT a Joke... Take an old Client (don't know exactly till when this worked) and put 10 subforms in that form. Without any content... Then open the form: it will need several seconds up to a minute until it opens. Now put code Dim runfaster as Boolean runfaster=1 into any script section of the subforms and open the same form again: it will instantl open...

Comment: I honestly thought it was a joke, although deep in the back of my mind I guess I do remember somebody saying it was true.  But it's not specific to "runfaster", right?  Any code at all will do the trick. It's the "runfaster" that made me think it was a joke, because for years we all wanted that as a notes.ini setting, and that was definitely a joke!

Comment: Of course you are right. The code in "my" subforms was always: NotesIsStupid = True, and that did the Job as well ;-)